# JQuery DataTables with ASP.Net MVC 4 with Custom Buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I want to use Jquery Datatables at my MVC 4 project for grid based operations and general listing.

After some search i found JQuery Datatables and i decided to use it. At first everythings seems good but when i came to add custom row buttons for Details, Edit and Delete problems started.

In conventional way adding a button to a row is just adding code into to the relevant `<td> </td>`

But datatables is quite different, i got below sample code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9774102/423699

```
"aoColumnDefs" : [ 
                    {
                        "aTargets": [0],
                        "fnCreatedCell" : function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol){
                            var b = $('<button style="margin: 0">edit</button>');
                            b.button();
                            b.on('click',function(){
                                document.location.href = oData[0];
                                return false;
                            });
                            $(nTd).empty();
                            $(nTd).prepend(b);
                        }
                    },
```

As previously mentions we have three buttons and some screens have optional buttons and they appear after some if-else conditions.
Also until datatables we were using Html.ActionLink and css things to show buttons; but after using datatables it becomes very hard to put buttons.

So i think may be we do something wrong and you can help us to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think click events are added when apending to another element. So I would suggest adding the click event after the button is prepended.

```
"aoColumnDefs" : [
{
    "aTargets": [0],
    "fnCreatedCell" : function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol){
        $(nTd)
            .empty()//Empty
            .prepend('<button style="margin: 0">edit</button>')// prepend the button to the td
            .filter("button")// filter the results to the button element
                 .button()// add the jquery button effects
                 .on('click',function(){// attach the click event to the "filtered" button
                     document.location.href = oData[0];
                     return false;
                  });
    }
},
```